# inicializar input date con fecha actual y hora c#

Tags: c#, razor

Tengo este input:

```html
   <div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">
          <label>Fecha Inicio</label>
          <input id="startDate" value="@...." class="form-control" type="date" />
    </div>
```

Como puedo poner la fecha actual junto con la hora a 00:00:00.000, aunque esta no se mire, ya que la ocuparia para sacar datos dentro de un rango de fecha, necesito que este por default

Con Razor o con js, puede ser con cualquiera de las dos maneras..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La implementación con JavaScript podría ser usando *toISOString* y removiendo la parte del tiempo, quedando sólo con la de la fecha.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const dateInput = document.getElementById('startDate')
  // formato ISO yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.ffffff
  dateInput.value = new Date().toISOString() // fecha actual en formato iso
    // seleccionamos lo que esta a la izquierda de la T, que es la parte de la fecha
    .split('T')[0]

})
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 ml-auto">
          <label>Fecha Inicio</label>
          <input id="startDate" class="form-control" type="date" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es hacerlo con Blazor.

En el controller puedes enviar la fecha a la vista:

```
    var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    ViewBag.CurrentDateTime = currentDateTime;
```

Por ejemplo:

```
public ActionResult MiVista()
{
    var currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    ViewBag.CurrentDateTime = currentDateTime;
    return View();
}
```

Luego en la vista recuperas la variable currentDateTime y la muestas en el input

```
<input type="text" id="dateTimeInput" value="@ViewBag.CurrentDateTime" />
```